# rtmpt(e) stream on SSL Page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, ssl, rtmp

I'm developing audio streaming web service for PC browsers.
We want to use `rtmpt(e)` protocol for streaming with Flash plugin.
Main HTML page has `https://` URL.

The problem is, when our SWF try to connect streaming server (via HTTP tunnelling), some browser (i.e. Chrome) shows warning on the secure icon in the URL bar:

> Your connection to ???.???.com is encrypted with 128-bit
>   encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not
>   secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and
>   can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.

and on the developer console:

```
The page at 'https://***.***.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://stream.***.net/fcs/ident2': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
The page at 'https://***.***.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://***.***.***.113/open/1': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
...
```

I think this is because Flash uses Browser's URL loading facility when accessing HTTP.

**How can I avoid these warnings?**

We don't want to use `rtmp(e)` because `1935` may be blocked by firewall on user environment, nor `rtmps` because our streaming server doesn't support it.
And We don't want to use `http://` for main HTML because of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid these warnings?

Fix the [Mixed Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/). Load everything over HTTPS.

Comment: I'm loading every resources over HTTPS including SWF already. My problem is `flash.net.NetConnection` with `rtmpte://` protocol doesn't use HTTPS connection. Do you mean we CANNOT avoid this while using `rtmpt`?